# jQuery AutoComplete - Return multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm using jQuery AutoComplete, and I have an auto-complete search box to search for users.

**Default.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%= txtUser.ClientID %>").autocomplete('UsersAutoComplete.ashx');
    });

</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" />
```

**UsersAutoComplete.ashx**

```
public class UsersAutoComplete : IHttpHandler
{    
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        List<User> users = DataContext.Users
            .Where(u => u.Username.StartsWith(context.Request.QueryString["q"]))
            .Take(Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["limit"]))
            .OrderBy(u => u.Username)
            .ToList();

        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            context.Response.Write(user.Username + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it only returns the Username. I'd also like to return the user's UserID as well.

The results will still only show a list of Usernames, but when someone selects a user, I'd like to store the UserID for that user in a hidden value so that I can do whatever I need to with it. I'll be running a query on the selected user, and I'd rather lookup the user by UserID than by Username.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a class that contains the values you want returned. Then create a new instance of that class with the values and serialize the response using JSON.

That should be enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

EDIT: Here is how I do it.

```
$("#<%= txtUser.ClientID %>").autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: autocompleteSourceUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: { LookupPrefix: request.term, TotalResults: 10 },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.LookupItems,
                        function (item) {
                            var itemLabel = item.DisplayName;

                            if (itemLabel.length > 37)
                                itemLabel = itemLabel.substring(0, 37) + "...";

                            return { label: itemLabel, value: item.DisplayName, data: item }
                        }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            selectedItemData = ui.item.data;
        }
    });
```

This is how I setup the autocomplete with the custom class returned. My class being returned  has the following structure:

```
{ Id: int, DisplayName: string }
```

Notice also the select function. That stores an internal reference to the data item that was returned. So when I need to submit that info I can just look at the selectedItemData and use all the properties of the class at that time as well.

I hope this helps a little more. But the part for you to work with would be in the success method where I assign the object to the item.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me halfway there. But where is the UserID stored for each user in the results? As a class for each li? And how can I store it?

Comment: Well you would create a class with a username and userid property. Then return the serialized class to the autocomplete code. It will serialize it. You can tell autocomplete that data coming back is JSON. Then just use the properties like you would normally. Let me put in example.

Comment: I can handle returning a JSON result, my confusion is what to do on the front-end after I get that data. I need a way to relate each item in the results with a UserID, but I'm not sure how.